# How do I get this GNOME software center app?

Tags: gnome

I've installed GNOME 3.8, and opened the software center. Although, I cant seem to find the apps described in [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/10-best-features-in-gnome-3-8), such as Bijiben and maps. 
This [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0HreexQ8Tdk) shows the software center I'm looking for.

How do I get this app? Also, do I need to upgrade GNOME 3.10, or is it about adding a certain Repo?

Answer (score 0):

Gnome-software isn't available in the Ubuntu software center. Most of the other gnome core apps, however, are available and are quite beautiful/functional. Since most of them are so new, it's just taking a while to filter in. However, they're definitely worth taking a look at what you can find.